# Convert big endian to little endian from AS3 ByteArray in C

Tags: c

I'm using FlasCC to allow me to render a video from AS3 using FFmpeg. Doing an endian swap in AS3 is very slow I was running some tests and removing my endian swap on my video ByteArray before sending the video bytes (for that frame) to rendered cuts out about half of my rendering time. I'm wanting to see if I can make the endian swap quicker by doing it in C but I've never done an endian swap before in C or C++ and some of the posts I've found are a bit complex.

I'm taking in a pointer as a uint8_t to my ByteArray and want to swap the endian from big to little using C. Could anyone point me in the right direction or give me some sample code to do so?

The ByteArray should be holding RGB32 data but it's in a big endian and I need it in a big endian for processing using ffmpeg.

Edit:

Currently using:

```
int i = 0;
int j = bufferSize - 1;
int temp;
while (i < j)
{
  temp = buffer[i];
  buffer[i] = buffer[j];
  buffer[j] = temp;
  i++;
  j--;
}
```

Comment: If you already have a `uint8_t` array, that's nothing more than reversing the array.

Comment: Bytes don't have endianness, only multi-bytes have an endianness. What kind of data do you want to change endianness?

Comment: @ouah AS3 ByteArray's have an Endianness of either big or little. When you use getPixels() on bitmap data you get back a ByteArray of RGB32 information in Big Endian format. I want to swap it to little endian format to pass through to FFmpeg which takes in RGB32 pixels and processes them. So I have an array of bytes sorry, I think I was unclear.

Comment: @masfo My uint8_t is just a pointer to the ByteArray that is in domain memory from AS3 and FlasCC.

Comment: 8-bit pointers? OK. I don't know FlasCC nor AS3, but a `ByteArray` should be something like `unsigned char []` or `uint8_t []`, in which case this is just reversing these arrays. As Ouah's said, bytes don't have endianness.

Comment: @ElliotBlackburn Even when there are RGB32 values in that byte array it doesn't make much sense to talk about big and little endian, because those are still numbers that fit into 8 bits each. So maybe you want to reordering the components somehow? What do you have?  RGBA?  What do you want to have in the end?  ABGR?  BRGA?

Comment: @mafso I dislike AS3, hopefully we'll be moving away from it after this is finished! I've just reversed the array as suggested but when I then render the video the colours are correct but the entire video is upside down. So I was wondering if I was doing it correctly or if I needed a bitshift. I'll do some more digging in this case.

Comment: Your array holds the pixels, so `arr[0]`…`arr[3]` is RGB32 for one pixel, `arr[4]`…`arr[7]` for the next, and you want to reorder to `arr[3], arr[2], arr[1], arr[0], arr[7], arr[6], arr[5], arr[4], ...`?

Comment: Just use network byte order and these functions: http://linux.die.net/man/3/htonl (hton* on sender and ntoh* on receiver)

Answer (score 3):

the fastest way to byteswap is to use machine instructions designed for it, namely `bswap` and `pshufb`(SSSE3) on x86 processors.
good compilers have pattern matchers to use the instructions for the common masking based implementations.

```
xswapped32 = ((x & 0xffu) << 24) | ((x & 0xff00u) << 8) |
             ((x & 0xff0000u) >> 8) | (x >> 24);
```

Take care to ensure your data is aligned when casting from `int8` to `uint32` on platform that do not allow unaligned loads.

the easiest way to use them reliably is to use compiler intrinsics, e.g. with GCC or clang:

```
__builtin_bswap32(var)
```

using pshufb can be faster if you your machine has SSSE3:

```
const __m128i cmask4 = _mm_set_epi8(12, 13, 14, 15, 
                                    8, 9, 10, 11, 
                                    4, 5, 6, 7,
                                    0, 1, 2 ,3);
_mm_shuffle_epi8(vectorvalue, cmask4);
```

Comment: Make sure both x and xswapped32 variables are unsigned int (uint32), otherwise the byteswapping goes wrong

Answer (score 1):

If the size of each **logical element** in you data is 1 byte, then nothing needs to be done.

Otherwise, you can use the following function:

```
void Reverse(uint8_t* arr,int arr_size,int elem_size)
{
    int i,j;
    uint8_t temp;
    for (i=0; i<arr_size; i+=elem_size)
    {
        for (j=0; j<elem_size/2; j++)
        {
            temp = arr[i+j];
            arr[i+j] = arr[i+j+elem_size-1];
            arr[i+j+elem_size-1] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this form of byteswapping is not optimal for the sizes 2, 4 and 8 as it is hard for the compiler to detect this as a byteswap and replace it special purpose optimized machine instructions. Using masks to swap the small sizes typically plays better with compiler pattern matchers.

Comment: @jtaylor: You would have to ensure that the array itself is aligned to 2, 4 or 8 byte address, in order to safely apply that sort of optimization. The code above assumes that this is not the case.

Comment: on x86 the bswap instruction has no alignment requirements. On platforms without unaligned loads you probably do not want to have your memory unaligned for byteswapping in the first place because it will be slow, but you are right one has to be careful.

Comment: Thanks @barakmanos I had my facts a bit wrong I think and this was what I was what I needed. My colours are now correct however my entire image is upside down which is odd. Any ideas?

Comment: @BlueHat: up-side-down by rows only, by columns only or by both (i.e., the top-left corner should be on the bottom-left, on the top-right or on the bottom-right)?

Comment: @barakmanos top right should be at bottom left, a 180 flip has happened basically. Any ideas?

Comment: @BlueHat: Not really, but it sounds like the problem is on your "AS3 side", when you read the binary data from the image. You can work-around this problem easily, by reversing the order of elements (**not the order of bytes**).

Comment: @barakmanos originally we had it so we got the pixel bytes into a ByteArray (big-endian) and then iterated through each element and wrote it to a little endian array. It's a slow process that's taking a lot of time as we do it per frame.

I've just done a bit of code that swaps the elements of the array (edited into the original question for formatting) and that is giving me this 180 flip thing. It's rather odd if you ask me, since in theory this should work?

Comment: @BlueHat: So the suggested answer does not solve your problem of converting from Big-Endian to Little-Endian?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I actually just figured it out myself. What everyone said so far has been technically correct but not what I've been looking for. Hopefully this may help someone else.

When using BitmapData.getPixels() in AS3 you get an array like so:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6...
A R G B A R G...
```

To swap the endianness you need to essentially need to swap the A and B values, and the R and G values. But keep the ARGB grouping for that pixel together. This is why the reversal of the array gave me the correct colours but the entire picture was inverted, I had changed the endian but mostly as a bi-product of moving the top right pixel to the bottom left (and so on).

To correctly switch the RGB32 endian I need to change the above representation to:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6...
B G R A B G R...
```

Which will give the correct input for FFmpeg in this instance.

However a fast way was to use the pixel format in my FFmpeg API that means I have no endian conversion. Instead of using PIX_FMT_RGB32 I used AV_PIX_FMT_ARGB.